# Passing file descriptors to processes created with spawn_link

Tags: erlang

I am opening a file:

```
{ok, FD} = file:open(AcctFile, [binary, raw, read, {read_ahead, ?ACCT_READAHEAD_SZ}])
```

I print the FD and see something like: `{file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.421>,16}}`.
I now spawn a process and pass the file descriptor to it:

```
spawn_link(fun() -> get_accts(AcctFile, FD, #bookmark{needsrefresh = true}) end).
```

In `get_accts` I print the FD and it's the same as above.

However `file:read_line` and other file operations on this FD just hang (if I call them on the FD before passing it to the spawned process, they work.)  What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you opened the file in `raw` mode.  Files that were opened in `raw` mode cannot be used in a different process (from the one who opened it).

From Erlang [`file` module documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html) :

> raw
>
> - . . .
> - Only the Erlang process that opened the file can use it.